# Cassandra OOM on 4 nodes

Tags: java, cassandra, out-of-memory

I'm running a 4-nodes (4GB, 4GB, 4GB, and 6GB RAM) cassandra cluster, and have 10 client applications, 8 threads per app.

It is falling with

```
CassandraDaemon.java:185 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/,5,main]
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:396) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:338) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Row$RowSerializer.deserialize(Row.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Row$RowSerializer.deserialize(Row.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeSliceReply$RangeSliceReplySerializer.deserialize(RangeSliceReply.java:80) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeSliceReply$RangeSliceReplySerializer.deserialize(RangeSliceReply.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageIn.read(MessageIn.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:200) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessages(IncomingTcpConnection.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:91) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2016-04-25 19:42:50,491 StatusLogger.java:56 - RequestResponseStage              0         0
```

In log before this falling I see multiply

```
DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-7] 2016-04-25 19:38:16,830 AbstractQueryPager.java:89 - Got empty set of rows, considering pager exhausted
DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-6] 2016-04-25 19:38:16,841 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]],
```

And also it is another exception in all logs:

```
2016-04-27 19:43:22,675 CassandraDaemon.java:185 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:14,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor.uncompress(LZ4Compressor.java:113) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.reBufferMmap(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:192) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.reBuffer(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:237) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedThrottledReader.reBuffer(CompressedThrottledReader.java:44) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.seek(RandomAccessReader.java:287) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.seekToCurrentRangeStart(BigTableScanner.java:180) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.access$200(BigTableScanner.java:53) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(BigTableScanner.java:261) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(BigTableScanner.java:241) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.hasNext(BigTableScanner.java:221) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.<init>(MergeIterator.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator.get(MergeIterator.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionIterable.iterator(CompactionIterable.java:57) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:165) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:256) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

I have tried to uncomment 
        MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
        HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
in cassandra-env.sh,

I have tried to change column_index_size_in_kb / rpc_max_threads in cassandra.yaml, but still no changes. Also, all requests are very slow.

On a client side i use

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(/* 4 points */)
            .build();
    cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(100000);//because it always falls with read timeout
    session = cluster.connect("keyspace");
    mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
```

How can i get a bottleneck of my program? And how can i prevent cassandra OOM?

UPD: running top on server, i got

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                         
3597 root      20   0 9073600 4.536g 137728 S 100.4 58.2  24:24.25
```

And also i modified /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf to optimal values

Comment: I think what's happening here, is your read timeout is way to big.  Leaving it at the default should be plenty, if your queries are performant.  And my hunch is that your queries are where the problem is at.  Can you post your table structure, along with your queries, and how many rows you are trying to get back at once?

Comment: I download texts, so i create two tables: ids_to_download: id int, reserved_by_ip text, PRIMARY KEY (id,reserved_by_ip) and text: id PRIMARY KEY int, description keyspace.description (UDT), full_text text; (text can be very long up to several MB). And the first query i do, is "SELECT * FROM ids_to_download where reserved_by_ip='' limit 1000 ALLOW FILTERING;". Is the problem in it? Should i better store in ids_to_download only int ids?  And also, create keyspace with replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy',  'replication_factor': '4' is ok for this configuration?

Comment: I deleted timeout and got "Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
". Cassandra on servers is alive for several minutes, and then dies.